# How to call Google Calendar API

Tags: javascript, express, server, google-calendar-api

I am trying to use Google Calendar's API code, and it doesn't work as expected. I thought, app would call index.html and a functioning authorization and calendar invite would display. Any help would be great

Running node app.js in terminal. Expected authorization function would run when authorize button clicked

https://github.com/byrnenp/googapi

Comment: you cannot access `env` variables from html like that. and also share the error message which you are getting.

Comment: please edit your question and include your code